# Conditional sumproduct formula, incorporates: an excluded variable, offset/match lookup

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, offset

I need to calculate a weighted average rental rate, conditional on a few factors.

[Link to my example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWWix.jpg)

I need the calculation to include all properties, but able to adjust out the Subject Property's values...

I can't figure out how to have the sumproduct array `[=sumproduct(rates*units)/sum of units]` exclude the Subject Property's values.

I'm pretty new to Stack - is there a better way to post example files?

Comment: probably better to include a link to an actual workbook, e.g. via dropbox or similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer to use `INDEX` rather than `OFFSET` but you could do the `SUMPRODUCT` like this:

`=SUMPRODUCT(INDEX(C6:I9,MATCH(C20,B6:B9,0),0),INDEX(C12:I15,MATCH(C20,B12:B15,0),0),(C3:I3=C19)*(C2:I2<>C18))/B24`

where `B24` is the `14` from the result of your first formula

That should give you a result of 580

Comment: Checked back on this thread and realized I thanked the wrong user - thanks Barry!

Comment: Also - how would I go about calculating the weighted average rate for the Region 1 properties (again, excluding the subject property), but for ALL floor plans, not just one unit type?  this is giving me trouble, as the array sizes are not the same...